# removing the image from the tab bar of a Node.JS/Javascript page

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-lex

I have this [aws lex web-ui](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui) `Node.JS` based project to which I am working on making modifications. It has a default pic which shows up on the `toolbar` and the `tab`. I want to remove these from the webpage. I am not at all familiar with `JavaScript` but after digging through I was able to remove the default pic showing up on the `toolbar` by commenting out the `toolbarLogo` on line 151 in file `aws-lex-web-ui/lex-web-ui/src/config/index.js`. For the pic showing on the tab I commented out the `favIcon` on line 154 in the same file as above but I still see the default pic showing up on the tab. This is snapshot of how it looks:

[image]

You can see a little flower showing up on the top left of the tab which I want to remove. Can anyone help me out by pointing to the right file and line which I should remove to get rid of this default pic?

Comment: Remove the favicons rel in the head tag. If you've already done that. Favicons are usually saved to the browser cache and will remain locally. Make sure you clear your cache in your browser.

Comment: @matt I didn't looked into clearing out the caches. I had removed the favicon rel but didn't realized that it was cached and that's why was confused why it was still showing up. Thanks. If you can post this comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the favicons rel in the head tag. If you've already done that. Favicons are usually saved to the browser cache and will remain locally. Make sure you clear your cache in your browser.